# What desktop computer hardware specifications are most important for database heavy applications?

Tags: memory, performance, ssd, cache, database

I am purchasing a new personal desktop computer with the hope of improving performance for database-heavy applications (mostly data mining). I will want versatile hardware for all sorts of future projects, but what would be the most important hardware elements which would improve performance on a project with the following qualities:

- A static main data table with 100 million records, 5 integer columns
- Many complicated select queries on this table, with self joins, counts, and group by statements all in single queries
- The select queries can be run in parallel

I figure that the most important hardware components will be processor cache, RAM, and hard drive speed, considering database queries spend most of their time doing memory accesses. I have been looking at a special edition Dell XPS 8700 desktop, which has:

```
Processor:         4th Generation Intel Core™ i7-4770 Processor (8M Cache)
RAM:               24GB Dual Channel DDR3 1600MHz
Secondary Storage: 2TB 7200 RPM SATA Hard Drive + Intel SRT 32GB SSD Cache
```

So, for a database heavy application, will these specifications be very helpful in improving the speed of queries? Are any of the processor cache, RAM, or secondary storage the clear weak link in the system? Also, the 32GB SSD cache is optional, is that something that I can expect to have a large impact on database performance?

Comment: Use a Real SSD which only hosts the DB and a separate SSD for the Windows. For a Server you can buy the Intel Xeon E3-1230 v3 if you don't need the IGP which is par of the 4770.